# Python post request display result on php page

Tags: php, python, redirect

I want to use python to redirect a php page which originally redirects to something else. 
I get the response right, but I am not able to see the result on the php page.

Python code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.notarealwebsite/test.php'
values = {'redirect'='http://www.google.com')

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url + "?" + data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page

import webbrowser
url_2 = "http://www.notarealwebsite/test.php"
new = 2 
webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
```

PHP code: /test.php

```
<script>
   function redirect(){
     window.location.replace("?redirect=test5.php");
   }
   setTimeout("redirect()", 5000)
</script>

<?php

   if(isset($_GET['redirect'])){
      $redirect_url = $_GET['redirect'];
      header("Location: " . $redirect_url);
   }
?>
<div>This page will direct in 5 seconds</div>
```

The page test.php still redirects to http://www.notarealwebsite/test5.php instead of http://www.google.com even though the response is of google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the following lines in Python Code:
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
==>
    webbrowser.open(url + "?" + data,new=new)